# SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services Report Definition Customization Extensions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, documentation, reporting-services

I've been looking into report definition customization extensions (RDCE) in SQL2K8 recently and I've been at a loss to find much documentation or even chatter on the internet about it.

MSDN has a brief overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281022.aspx

And the sample report from this book [http://www.amazon.com/Applied-Microsoft-Server-Reporting-Services/dp/0976635313/ref=pd_bbs_sr_2?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1221629676&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0976635313) is something, but I was wondering if anyone had real experience with this and how it worked out for them.  And if anyone has other references worth looking at I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I do not have an answer for you but here is another page from MSDN on RDCE
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152934.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally MS publish examples on CodePlex (http://www.codeplex.com/MSFTRSProdSamples). But I didn't see any example for RDCE.

Sorry, but MS had never good documentation for reporting extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you are trying to accomplish but you can generate RDLs dynamically for SSRS Local Reports.

Check out this article from MSDN: [Creating the RDL Generator Visual Studio Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms167274.aspx)

For more examples of Dynamic RDL generations, check out the downloadable sample files on this page (dynamic RDL examples are on the bottom right corner of the page): [gotreportviewer? ReportViewer Control in Visual Studio 2008](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/)